# How to add scroll bar to richtext box wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I add a horizontal and vertical scroll bar inside a rich text box in wpf c# in the easiest way possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself at all? Or any research? SO isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
richtextbox.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
```

Hope this helps!